# Display text typed in textarea is always behind one step

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea in a form. While typing the text is displayed in a `<p>` as well as the number of characters in the textarea. The problem is that the first character is not perceived. So when I type the first character, the remaining chars is still 75 and the character is not displayed in the `<p>.` When I type "abc", only "ab" is displayed and the remaining chars is 73 instead of 72. After this I delete the "c" from the end then "abc" is displayed in the `<p>`. It's like it's always behind one step.

With a simple `<input type="text">` it's working fine.

```
<textarea  name="text" cols="56" rows="2" onKeyDown="drawAd();" onKeyUp="drawAd();" onFocus="drawAd();" maxlength="75" >
  <?php echo $text?>
</textarea>

function drawAd() 
{
    var draw_adtext = document.forms["MyForm"]["adtext"].value;
    var adtext = document.getElementById('p_adtext');
    var adtext2 = document.getElementById('p_adtext2');
    if (draw_adtext != "") {
        adtext.innerHTML = draw_adtext;
        adtext2.innerHTML = draw_adtext;
    } else {
        adtext.innerHTML = "";
        adtext2.innerHTML = "";
    }

   document.getElementById('textcount').innerHTML = 75 - document.forms["MyForm"]["adtext"].value.length + " chars left";
}
```

Ps: I know  `maxlength` is not an official attribute of textarea and I know how to handle it (just in case someone noted it).

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XhFzD/1/ . After I assumed a lot and cleaned up a bunch of stuff. Are you sure there's no whitespace characters because your `<?php echo $text?>` has some spaces before and after it on its line? All spaces are counted inside of a `<textarea>`

Comment: I also tried it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/gxsWm/) and it worked. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: @Ian: Nope, that part is fine (I removed it to check). The problem should be in other part of the code because it works in a blank .html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, my question is too localized, as it turned out. Thank you for trying my code out on jsfiddle, i didn't think about trying only this part out on a blank webpage.

I had this code after the  tag which messed up everything. Removing it solved the problem.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() { 
  var txts = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA') 

  for(var i = 0, l = txts.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(/^[0-9]+$/.test(txts[i].getAttribute("maxlength"))) { 
      var func = function() { 
        var len = parseInt(this.getAttribute("maxlength"), 10); 

        if(this.value.length > len) { 
          //alert('Maximum length exceeded: ' + len); 
          this.value = this.value.substr(0, len); 
          return false; 
        } 
      }

      txts[i].onkeyup = func;
      txts[i].onblur = func;
    } 
  } 
}
</script>
```

I don't think I deserved any points for solving this, but I accept it as a solution to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided is not functional as is (it refers to forms that don't exist, etc.).
But I've recreated it at jsfiddle.net/v2eHk/, and as far as I can tell, it works just fine. Is there more information about how to get the problem to occur?

Comment: This is not a solution. I am experiencing with this that's why I have both.